# Opening a saved pdf on client

Tags: pdf, azure, asp.net-web-api, crystal-reports

I am exporting crytsal report to pdf format and saving the pdf on azure cloud. This code is written in web api. I am also able to download the pdf on client. Is there any way with which I can open this saved pdf file on client side by either using server side code or using jQuery. I just want to keep the file open for the user to view.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a link point to the PDF file address with response header `"response-content-disposition": "inline; filename=this.pdf", "response-content-type": "application/pdf"`. Then I think the browser will launch proper PDF plugin to show it.